# A connection was successfully established... (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption( ssl /tls) handshake failed)

Tags: .net, docker, ssl, dockerfile, tls1.2

I do have a docker container for a proxy (nginx), user interface and API (.NET 6). The API is giving me an error of `A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption( ssl /tls) handshake failed)`.

Deployment Environment: `CentOS 7`

SQL Server Version: `Microsoft SQL 2016 SP2`

Connection String: `Data Source=${DB_HOST};Initial Catalog=${DB_NAME};Persist Security Info=True;User ID=${DB_USERNAME};Password=${DB_PASSWORD};MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

Solutions I'd tried:

1. Enabling TLS 1.2 in regedit in Database server.
2. Restarted SQL server agent.
3. Added `TrustServerCertificate=True` or `Encrypt=False` in the connection string.
4. Added `RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

Nothing worked from all of this solutions. Badly needed help!

Comment: In general, you get a handshake error when the public key doesn't match with the private key. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Are you pertaining to the `ssl_certificate` under the nginx config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved my concern by combining the following.

- Used `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of `Systems.Data.SqlClient`.
- Added commands to Dockerfile of the API

`RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

`RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`

- Added `TrustServerCertificate=True` to connection string of the database.

This lowers the TLS version of docker image or container to TLSv1. However, this is not the best solution. It would be better to upgrade the SQL server to allow the connection to accept TLSv1.2. Which in my case is not applicable.